# Fragment transactions, actionbar & backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

In  my main activity, I have an actionbar with `NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`. The contents of each tab is a listfragment.

I'd like to make it so that that when a listitem is clicked, a new fragment is brought into view, and the actionbar mode is changed to `NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD` (so that the tabs are now hidden).

I've managed to get this to work with the following code:

In the listitemclick method:

```
        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);

        Fragment albumListFragment = new AlbumListFragment();
        albumListFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, albumListFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        ft.commit();

        Log.i("FragmentList", "Item clicked: " + id);
```

The problem is when I press the back button, the tabs are still gone, and the previous fragment doesn't come back into view.

Am I doing something wrong.. Is it something to do with the fragment backstack? Should I go about it another way, or even override the backpress?

--Edit--

For clarity - I am calling addToBackStack when I call fragmenttransaction.replace, but when I press the back button, the previous fragment is not restored.

Comment: check this link once     http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments_tutorial

Comment: Thanks, but not particularly helpful for this question..

Comment: Using addToBackStack is what you want.  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions

Comment: instead of  `ft.addToBackStack(null);` can you try `ft.addToBackStack("fragment_tag");` ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a little late, I tried to re-construct your problem for hours but didnot succeed. I tried to switch from a listview in a fragment hosted by a ActionBar Tab to another view by the way described in your question(i.e. ft.replace(android.R.id.content, albumListFragment);) but with no effect. After some google and stackoverflow, I use [this way](http://www.lucazanini.eu/2013/android/how-to-replace-a-fragment-in-an-actionbar-in-mode-navigation_mode_tabs/) to successfully switch the fragment within the tab, yet with no problem as you have.

**As the "action bar is not showing correctly" problem**, its probably caused by the backstack revert and UI change as describe in [android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments). you might try to override the onBackStackChanged() callback and re-construct the UI.

**As the "backstack does not bring the previous fragment back" problem**, you may want to post a little more code to help others re-construct the problem to find the answer.

Wish helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced exactly the same issue and figured it out that the problem only occurs when you set the ActionBar back to NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD.

The only solution for me was to place the new fragment with no tabs in a helper activity which has NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD. Then you can easily use the back button functionality provided by Android to go back to the activity with NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS and retain its state.

Answer (score 0):

[FragmentTransaction.replace()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) actually removes the previous fragment in the layout and add new instance of the fragment.

Try using [FragmentTransaction#show()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#show%28android.app.Fragment%29) and [FragmentTransaction#hide()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#hide%28android.app.Fragment%29) methods instead of replace.

Comment: Or you can use FragmentTransaction.detach()

Answer (score -1):

The backstack ends the current activity and goes to the previous activity, not the previous fragment.  (See the backstack guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

You could force, as you suggested, the behavior by overriding onBackPressed, however, I don't know that I would change the natural Android behavior in such a way.  If you look at other apps, particularly core apps, that do similar things the back button does not go to a previous fragment, but a previous activity.

Also you do have total control on the behavior of the "up" button (that is your app icon on the action bar with a left arrow).  You have to programatically set it up to be used as a button as described in the ActionBar guide (let me know if you need to know how to do this) and with that you could have it set up a previous fragment on a stack that you maintain somewhere.

Comment: From the docs: Before you call commit(), however, you might want to call addToBackStack(), in order to add the transaction to a back stack of fragment transactions. This back stack is managed by the activity and allows the user to return to the previous fragment state, by pressing the Back button.

Comment: @Frohnzie thanks for that, but the problem is I am using addToBAckStack(), and it isn't restoring the previous fragment when I press back..

Comment: @rascuache Code looks correct. I have done exactly the same thing. I am not sure what the issue is.  Using addToBackStack is the right thing.  Maybe you can post more code.